# Adding new item in C++ array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am pretty new to c++ and was trying to add a new string in C++ array. In Python we can add new items by .append(). Is there any function like this in C++?

Comment: Python does not have arrays, it only has a list. If you want the same complexity on accesses, you can use `std::list`. If you prefer an array `std::vector` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in C++ arrays are of a static size. I would recommend including the vector header and replacing the array with a std::vector. vector has a function to add a new entry

Comment: It would also be possible to use a pointer instead of an array and to use the `malloc()` and `realloc()` functions.

Comment: @MartinRosenau `malloc` and `realloc` will not work well together with objects.

Comment: Indeed, but that would require you to know the index of the data entry. OP is asking for a equivalent function. That would only be possible using a vector.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's right. However, in most other programming languages an array of objects is more like `MyClass *myArray[]` in C++, not like `MyClass myArray[]`, because you would do: `myArray[9] = new MyClass()`. And allocating an array whose elements are pointers to objects would work well using `realloc()`.

Comment: @MartinRosenau no, in C++ you would do `std::vector<MyClass> myArray;` and `myArray.emplace_back(<constructor arguments>);`.

Comment: both methods are possible, but in c++ the use of vector is widely accepted as good practice

Comment: @mch However, there are use cases where you would not do this: If you don't have the C++ standard library available, for example - as it is the case in a project I am currently working on ...

Comment: That is correct. In most cases you would use a vector, except for when you don't have a standard library. I'm assuming that the OP has a standard library since they use string instead of const char*

Comment: @MartinRosenau The point wat that you cannot use `malloc`, `realloc`, and similar mechanisms in general, since they only allocate storage but do not create objects inside. (Except of some rare cases where objects are crated implicitly.)

Answer (score 1):

```
// Declaring Vector of String type
// Values can be added here using initializer-list syntax
std::vector<std::string> colour {"Blue", "Red", "Orange"};

// Strings can be added at any time with push_back
colour.push_back("Yellow");
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-strings-c-3-different-ways-create/